# Why can’t I get unicode characters?

Tags: xetex, luatex, compiling, unicode, unicode-math

I’m trying to typeset the unicode dice character in LaTeX. I’m using emacs, on Ubuntu 18.04. I’ve tried manually setting my `TeX-engine` to xelatex and lualatex, and I get the same thing.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}                                      
%\setmainfonta{TeX Gyre Termes}                            
\usepackage{unicode-math}                                  
%\usepackage{unixode}                                      
\begin{document}                                           
\symbol{"2680}                                             
A                                                          
⚀                                                          
B                                                          
$\dicei$                                                   
C                                                          
\dicei                                                     
D                                                          
$\clubsuit$                                                  
E                                                          
$\varclubsuit$                                               
F                                                          
\end{document}                                             


%%% Local Variables:                                       
%%% mode: xelatex                                          
%%% TeX-master:                                            
%%% End:
```

This compiles to [image]

Comment: You can, but you need to use a font that contains that glyph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default math font, Latin Modern Math, does not have those characters.  You must load them from another font that does, such as XITS Math.  There are slightly different commands to do this in math mode, in text mode, and to make the Unicode character work in both modes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range={"2680-"2685}]

\newfontfamily\symbolfont{XITS}
\newcommand\textdicei{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2680}}}

\newunicodechar{^^^^2680}{\ifmmode\dicei\else\textdicei\fi}

\begin{document}                                           
^^^^2680                            
A                                                          
⚀                                                          
B                                                          
$\dicei$                                                   
C                                                          
\textdicei                                                     
D                                                          
$\clubsuit$                                                  
E                                                          
$\varclubsuit$                                               
F
$⚀$                                                      
\end{document}
```

[image: XITS font sample]

Answer (score 1):

I used the `epsdice` package, which allowed me to include unicode die faces without worrying about what font family I was using. I could generate faces easily then by calling `\epsdice{1}`, `\epsdice{2}`, and so forth.